# Rotate sprite around itself?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to rotate a circle in the middle of the screen, that is on a layer, that added to the main scene , but it rotates not around its center, but in a strange way up and down in some angel. seems that it rotates around the bottom left corner of screen.

```
 id rot1=[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.4 angle:10];
    id rot2=[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.4 angle:-20];
    id rot3=[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.4 angle:+20];
    id rotB=[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.2 angle:0];
    id seq=[CCSequence actions:rot1,rot2,rot3,rot2,rot3,rot2,rotB, nil];
    [mainButton runAction:seq];
```

whats wrong here ?
thanks .

Answer (score 1):

You should try and set the `anchorPoint` of the sprite:

```
mainButton.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5, 0.5);
```

The anchor point is defined in a relative scale (from 0 to 1) and it represents the point relative to which any transformation is applied; the sprite texture is also centred around the anchor point.

In the above example, the anchor point is set exactly at the center of the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

do you set your circle in center?if no then set it first

```
 circle_Sprite.position = ccp( 240, 160 );
```